# Error creating table with Spring Boot and Postgres

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot

I am trying to create an application using Spring and Postgres. Currently I have 3 Entities: `User`, `Role` and `UserRole`.

**User**

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Data
@Entity
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "lastName", nullable = true)
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "gender", nullable = false)
    private char gender;
    @Column(name = "email", nullable = true)
    private String email;


    public User() {}

    public User(String username, String password, String firstName, String lastName, char gender, String email) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

**Role**

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Data
@Entity
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "role_id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "description", nullable = false)
    private String description;

    public Role () {}

    public Role (String name, String description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }

}
```

**UserRole**

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Data
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserRole {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_role_id")
    private Long id;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
    private Role role;

    public UserRole () {}

    public UserRole (User user, Role role) {
        this.user = user;
        this.role = role;
    }
}
```

When running the application, `Role` and `UserRole` tables are created in the database correctly, but its not the case with `User` table. I will appreciate your help :).

Comment: When you startup your application, you got errors ?

Answer (score 0):

`user` is a reserved keyword in postgresql because of which it is not allowing to create the table with this name. Try with another name.